# Safari-style UIPopoverController from Toolbar

Tags: iphone, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I'm creating an iPad application which needs a `UIPopoverController` like this one (I mean, with buttons):

[image: sorry]

I tried using a `UIViewController` but it gives me an enormous popup with a white background.

Can anyone explain me how to make one? I cannot find any documentation or example code. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need [`-[UIActionSheet showFromBarButtonItem:animated:]`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIActionSheet/showFromBarButtonItem:animated:) instead of a UIPopoverController.