# iOS: UIPopoverController

Tags: ios

[image]

I am trying to create a popover as seen above.

It can be a button or a TableViewController with just one item.

I looked over a bunch of tutorials but they all seem way more complicated than necessary.

Is there a way to do this without creating a new ViewController? How?

Comment: Can you show us a bigger picture?

Comment: @Alexsander: Why would you need a bigger picture?  It's just a standard `UIPopover`.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579025/safari-style-uipopovercontroller-from-toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iPad, this is actually a UIActionSheet